# Loop through years in a dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to display the current year and 10 years before that year.

Is it any way to do that through JavaScript or jQuery?

Currently, I am manually inputting values.

**HTML:**

```
<span>Year:</span>
<select name="year">
    <option value="2014">2014</option>
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
    And so on....
</select>
```

I know how to get the current year in JavaScript

Here's what I have currently

```
var d = new Date();
var y = d.getFullYear();
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of what you've attempted to do in JavaScript?

Comment: Yes. You can do that. Did you try anything?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  var start_year = new Date().getFullYear();

  for (var i = start_year; i > start_year - 10; i--) {
    $('select').append('<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span>Year:</span>
<select name="year"></select>
```

But a templating engine like [mustache.js](http://mustache.github.io/) would be better suited for that job, so you can avoid having markup code in your javascript.

Answer (score 2):

html

```
<select name="example" id="select" ></select>
```

Javascript version

```
(function(){
    var start_year = new Date().getFullYear();
    var html ='';
    for (var i = start_year; i > start_year - 10; i--) {
       html += '<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>';
    }
   document.getElementById("select").innerHTML = html;
})()
```

Jquery version

```
$(function() {
  var start_year = new Date().getFullYear();
  var html = ''
  for (var i = start_year; i > start_year - 10; i--) {
    html += '<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>';
  }
 $("#select").html(html)
});
```